# Garbage Collector in c++

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I have an project and I must implement the garbage collector in c++.
Now I must deliver class diagrams, but I don't know how to do that.

Can someone explain me what garbage collector does? google didn't helped me!! I found a lot of things with a lot of classes and variables.

> We consider a simple language in which there are only two predefined
>   classes, Int and Real (as in Java), allocated on 4 or 8 bytes.
>
> - I have declarations like int a, real b
> - assignment statements (x=y)
> - return statements (return x)
>
> -When declaring an object, memory is allocated from a memory area corresponding dynamic allocation of proper size and free address,
>   object's reference counter is initialized to 1
>
> -Every assignment, increment reference count object. The same thing happens on passing values ​​present in function, as well as
>   instructions for return
>
> -Each time the function body ends where there is a declaration of an object, it decrements the reference counter
>
> -When an object's reference count has reached 0, it releases the memory

How many classes should I implement? There are only 2 predefined classes... each class must have an variable "counter", or there is a 3-rd class who has the counter?

Comment: This is called "reference counting", not "garbage collection".

Comment: Note dasblinkenlight's comment: use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I would have thought that "reference counting" could be considered a type/component of GC...

Comment: *"Can someone explain me what garbage collector does?"* -> read [the usual first stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) for almost any research.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - the terminology I've heard is "automatic memory management" versus "manual memory management". Garbage collection and reference counting are techniques for automatic memory management. Reference counting isn't quite as automatic, because you have to watch out for cycles (which prevent releasing memory).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I would think "garbage collection" and "reference counting" are both types of automatic memory management, but otherwise distinct. If you have "reference counting" there never will be garbage to collect in the first please.

Comment: The term "garbage collection" is a garbage term which can refer to a number of techniques.  It is most closely associated with the "mark and sweep" technique generally employed by Java, but (historically) can legitimately refer to reference counting and several other schemes.  It can be cyclical or continuous.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but first you ask what it does, and then you describe exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector is a periodic service which automatically deallocates the allocated memory when it is not used anymore.

Note that it doesn't deal with variables allocated on the stack, like

```
int a;
char b;
```

but with variables allocated in the heap (i.e., allocated using the `new` statement).

In practice, when you have a garbage collector, you don't need to explicitly `delete` allocated variables anymore, because the garbage collector will do this for you.

Comment: Other than "periodic service" you have the definition about right.  And in theory it CAN apply to automatic (stack) variables, but doesn't, in any real implementation.

Comment: @Jefffrey - He's not referring to the stack.